# Extending type definition in variable defined in lib.d.ts

Tags: typescript

I have legacy code to transform that makes use of mootools. Mootools introduces a new constructor function of 'Element' with two parameters. I did not find any type definition file for mootools, so I have to write my own.

The typescript standard library (lib.d.ts) defines Element as following:

```
  var Element: { prototype: Element; new(): Element; };
```

which makes it impossible to extend an existing interface.

What I was obviously trying is

```
interface Element {
        new(s: string, s2: any): Element;
}
```

But still, the compiler complains about

```
var c = new Element('p',{});
```

as `the contructor expected 0 arguments, but got 2`. What is the preferred workaround here?

---

The mootools constructor function

```
var Element = this.Element = function(tag, props){
    var konstructor = Element.Constructors[tag];
    if (konstructor) return konstructor(props);
    if (typeof tag != 'string') return document.id(tag).set(props);

    if (!props) props = {};

    if (!(/^[\w-]+$/).test(tag)){
        var parsed = Slick.parse(tag).expressions[0][0];
        tag = (parsed.tag == '*') ? 'div' : parsed.tag;
        if (parsed.id && props.id == null) props.id = parsed.id;

        var attributes = parsed.attributes;
        if (attributes) for (var attr, i = 0, l = attributes.length; i < l; i++){
            attr = attributes[i];
            if (props[attr.key] != null) continue;

            if (attr.value != null && attr.operator == '=') props[attr.key] = attr.value;
            else if (!attr.value && !attr.operator) props[attr.key] = true;
        }

        if (parsed.classList && props['class'] == null) props['class'] = parsed.classList.join(' ');
    }

    return document.newElement(tag, props);
};



// Browser
  var Browser = this.Browser = parse(navigator.userAgent, navigator.platform);




if (Browser.Element){
    Element.prototype = Browser.Element.prototype;
    // IE8 and IE9 require the wrapping.
    Element.prototype._fireEvent = (function(fireEvent){
        return function(type, event){
            return fireEvent.call(this, type, event);
        };
    })(Element.prototype.fireEvent);
}
```

Comment: Does that actually mean, it is not possible to write a proper type definition file for the mootools library?

Comment: you need to omit the declarations for the Dom and use a custom set of declarations. Does mootools actually replace the element built-in object in the browser? That's like terrible.

Comment: I put the definition of the mootools constructor in the question

Comment: can you point me to the JavaScript of mootools that is actually overwriting `window.Element`?

Comment: it is Browser.Element and I just added it

Comment: If you call the element Constructor from your own code, just use a type assertion to suppress the error. If you call it a lot that will be annoying.

Comment: Note that this. Element refers to window. Element

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend `Element` interface, what you need is to extend type of `Element` variable. That's a bit confusing, that's two separate entities from TS standpoint. Here's how you can do it:

```
declare const Element: { // If you do that in a .d.ts file, you don't need declare.
    prototype: Element; // Element here is interface, we leave it unchanged.
    new(): Element; // Standard constructor.
    new(s: string, n: number): Element; // Your custom constructor.
};

const e = new Element('1', 2);

e.nodeName; // => string, i.e. result object implements Element interface.
```

Comment: If I do that in a .d.ts file, the complainer complains about subsequent variable declarations, whether I add 'declare' or not. But - what works is: I replace 'declare const' by 'var' and put the definition on top of the .ts file within I actually use the new Element('1',2) constructor

Comment: Which means. I am happy but I would be happier if there was a way I could achieve that with modifying the `.d.ts` file only.

Comment: I understand the point you're making, but you should point out that `Element` is different in type position and value position.

Comment: For extensible declarations, the type would be another interface but since it's an anonymous type literal here it can't be extended. I believe that's intentional because something like adding a new Constructor would not make any sense because we can't replace the `Element` function object at runtime

Comment: Of course - I had appreciated it if Typescript had choosen an approach to make types look different than values.

Comment: "adding a new Constructor would not make any sense", still, this is what mootools does and mootools is a widely used library.

Comment: @Ferenjito there's a great way to avoid that confusion. Stop using classes. Period. The whole problem is conflating types and classes.

Comment: In that sense, 'Element' is the name of a built-in class as well as a type (in Typescript sense), isn't it?

Comment: The problem is people like to think about using the name of the class as the name of the type of the objects it produces. People wanted to do that so much in JavaScript that went typescript came along they just made that the way it works by default but you could Define otherwise for your own types for example by using a pair of interfaces

Comment: @Ferenjito anyway yes it's the name of both.