# Mootools Type Definition File

Tags: typescript, mootools

On http://definitelytyped.org/, there are a lot of typescript type definition files for various well-established javascript libraries. However, I cannot find any for MooTools though. Any ideas?

---

Just for the record: I started writing one one my own, but encountered severe problems: [Extending type definition in variable defined in lib.d.ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788489/extending-type-definition-in-variable-defined-in-lib-d-ts)